# Cassandra dsbulk loading data with null values doesnt implement it

Tags: cassandra, null

I have table with 2 fields: `id (primary key) fld_1 text`, i have 1 row in target table, for example `1 'hello world'`, and i have source tsv file with 1 row: `1\t`. After loading in target table i expect to see `1 null`, but the data doesnt change and i still get `1 'hello world'`
Setting `'dsbulk.schema.nullToUnset': 'false'` helped me, but it seems to me that it's not the best solution, are there any proper ways to load data with null values or the provided solution is ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you described is expected behavior, and DSBulk will avoid inserting null values by default because these cause tombstones in Cassandra.
Without overwriting the existing value of 'hello world', it would still exist with only an update to the id column.

If you plan to do any bulk loading, I would highly recommend avoiding the use of *dsbulk.schema.nullToUnset* and allowing it to default to true.  Instead of inserting null values, if you need something to be overwritten, include an empty string, a special character, the string 'null', etc.. but don't insert a lot of nulls as you'll needlessly create a lot of tombstones that can cause issues should this data need to be read.

Comment: Thanks Paul, and what about numeric fields and NULL values? Empty string doesnt seem to fit it...

Comment: you can still have an unset value for numeric fields, not necessarily a string in that case, but the unset value will still avoid the tombstone and DSBulk handles that nicely with the same parameter